# How to multiply all integer values in a Range in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, range

I created a range of integer value. Now I don't know how can I multiply those numbers and print them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A really handy way to multiply all values of an `Iterable` or range is to use [reduce](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html):

```
val m = (1..4).reduce { accumulator, element ->
    accumulator * element
}

println(m)
```

This would print:

> 24

The `accumulator` is initially the first value of the range. This will be multiplied with the next element and becomes the accumulator for the next run.